# How to find phase shift(angle) between two signals in simulink?

Tags: transformer, signal-processing, three-phase, phase-shift, simulink

[image]

So I'm doing a delta wye transformer in simulink and phase shift between these two signals should be 30 degrees, but how to show that, or calculate it? And how to find angle of each signal?

Comment: Using a cursor in the plot, maybe? " And how to find angle of each signal?" , the one is arbitrary, then all others are related to this reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the frequency and period of the wave.

Then the equation is:

Phase shift = 360 * time / wave period

Phase shift is in degrees and time is the time difference.

And you don’t want to find the angle of each signal rather you want to find the phase angle difference between the two sine waves.

Comment: But could I somehow find the phase of a signal?

Comment: Use the equation I gave in the answer for the phase

Answer (score 0):

Use Fourier block on each signal to "separate" the signal to magnitude and angle. Then subtract the angles using the subtract block.